# Extracting strings using a list of words

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the problem (for example)
I have a name file

```
VOG00001 
VOG00002 
VOG00004
```

and database file

VOG00001!962!834!Xu!sp|O31936|YOPB_BACSU_Putative_antitoxin_YopB
VOG00002!206!17!Xh!sp|Q5UPJ9|YL122_MIMIV_Putative_ankyrin_repeat_protein_L12
VOG00003!1284!960!Xr!sp|O22001|VXIS_BPMD2_Excisionase
VOG00004!353!304!Xu!sp|P03795|Y28_BPT7_Protein_2.8
VOG00005!253!60!Xu!REFSEQ_hypothetical_protein

I need to extract rows from the database that match the words in the file names

results:

VOG00001!962!834!Xu!sp|O31936|YOPB_BACSU_Putative_antitoxin_YopB
VOG00002!206!17!Xh!sp|Q5UPJ9|YL122_MIMIV_Putative_ankyrin_repeat_protein_L12
VOG00004!353!304!Xu!sp|P03795|Y28_BPT7_Protein_2.8

```
def log(x, y):
        output = open('output.txt', 'a')
        output.write(x + y)
        output.close
    
    
def main():
        i = 0
        nfile = 'input/' + input('Enter file with names: ')
        dfile = 'input/' + input('Enter file with data: ')
        names = list(open(nfile, 'r'))
        data = list(open(dfile, 'r'))
        while i != len(data):
            line = data[i]
            if 'VOG' in line:
                line1 = line.replace("!*" , "")
                if line1 in names:
                    log(line, data[i + 1])
            i += 1
    
        return(0)
    main()
```

I want to trim the unnecessary and compare with the list of names

```
line1 = line.replace("!*" , "")
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a dictionary based on the database file. The database file uses '!' to delimit the key so we just split the strings to find the key and associated the entire line with that key (the dictionary value). Then iterate over the "names" file and do lookups in the dictionary.

```
names = input('Enter path to names file: ')
db = input('Enter path to database file: ')

with open(names) as n, open(db) as d:
    dict_ = {}
    for line in map(str.strip, d):
        key, *_ = line.split('!')
        dict_[key] = line
    for name in map(str.strip, n):
        if (v := dict_.get(name)):
            print(v)
```

Comment: names = input('C:\\Users\\Sergey\\Desktop\\Test\\name.txt'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

Comment: @SergeyPotapov Do you know what the *input()* function does and how to use it?

Comment: Ok, I undastand. How to save print(v) to txt? sys.stdout = open("E:\\Shared folders\\Script\\test.txt", "a")
sys.stdout.close() don't work fo me

Comment: Thanks I got it. Sorry, I just started to learn and have to ask stupid questions...